# Shared image volume mount error in docker

Tags: django, docker, celery, celerybeat

I use `docker-compose` for running my containers in `docker`. I have two services - one of `celerybeat` and other the `web` (I have many others but considering only these services because they contain my problem).

`docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
.
.
.

celerybeat:
  image: web-image
  volumes:
    - /home/ubuntu/celerybeat:/code/celerybeat
  command: >
    /bin/ash -c "su -m celery -c 'celery -A <application_here> beat -s /code/celerybeat/celerybeat-schedule'"

web:
  image: web-image
  volumes:
    - /home/ubuntu/celerybeat:/code/celerybeat
  command: >      
    <some_command_to_run_server>
```

In my `Dockerfile` I have added these commands for proper permissions

```
RUN mkdir celerybeat
RUN touch celerybeat/celerybeat-schedule
RUN chown -R celery:celery celerybeat
```

**Note: In my compose file structure written above I have provided volume mounts for both containers (but actually I am using one at a time), for the ease of not writing the compose files again and again**.

The problem is actually here only. Technically the volume mount should be provided only in the celerybeat service. When I write volume mount for `celerybeat-schedule` in the celerybeat docker service I get `permission denied`. Whereas when I write the volume mount command in the web service celerybeat service starts happily. What is happening here can anyone explain me? I need a fix for this.

Comment: When you say you write the volume mount command in the web service celerybeat service and it starts happily, what command are you running exactly?

Comment: I fixed the issue although I still can't understand this. The issue was that I was running the command for starting the beat service as a celery user. But when I started the service without adding the `su -m celery -c` bit, it worked. Why is this issue arising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of operations - `docker build` then `docker run` (with `docker-compose up` counting as a `docker run`.

When you mount a volume, the files and folders in that volume are owned by root. Having `RUN chown -R celery:celery celerybeat` would work if you didn't mount a volume. When you bind mount the volume in your `docker run`/`docker-compose up`, anything that exists at /code/celerybeat is overwritten, including permissions.

So when you run celerybeat as root, you're good in this case. If you run it as the celery user as you have tried, that user can't access /code/celerybeat because as a bind mount volume, it's owned by root.

Instead of `chown`ing the directory in your Dockerfile, run `chown` as part of an entrypoint script. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

chown -R celery:celery celerybeat
/bin/ash -c "su -m celery -c 'celery -A <application_here> beat -s /code/celerybeat/celerybeat-schedule'"
```

This script, and thus chown, execute *after* the bind mount, where `RUN chown -R celery:celery celerybeat` executes *before* the bind mount, and is overwritten by it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is below

```
volumes:
    - /home/ubuntu/celerybeat:/code/celerybeat
```

By doing the above volume mapping, you effectively cancel the below

```
RUN chown -R celery:celery celerybeat
```

And inherit the permissions from the volume mount. The fix is either not to use the celery user or use below in your yaml

```
command: >
  /bin/ash -c "chown -R celery:celery /code/celerybeat && su -m celery -c 'celery -A <application_here> beat -s /code/celerybeat/celerybeat-schedule'"
```

Comment: thanks Tarun! :), same answer, gave him the upvote because "distribution of wealth"